# awk if else condition when string is not present in the file

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to convert a multi-line block to a single record and then trying to run a search operation on it. I am running `lspci -v` as the input command, but to I have mock the data for this question.

**Input data:**

```
name: foobar
data: 123 bad

name: foozoo
data: 123 good

name: foozoo
data: 123 bad

name: zoobar
data: 123 good

name: barzpp
data: 123 bad
```

First I converted the input data that was in blocks into single-line records.

```
awk -v RS='' '{$1=$1}1' xx
name: foobar data: 123 bad
name: foozoo data: 123 good
name: foozoo data: 123 bad
name: zoobar data: 123 good
name: barzpp data: 123 bad
```

Now I am searching for a string "`foozoo`" and this gives me desired results. Here, I am first checking if `foozoo` is present on the line, and then I am checking if `.*good` is present in the same line. This works fine.

```
awk -v RS='' -v var=foozoo '{$1=$1}; {if(match($0,var)) if(match($0,var ".*good")) print var " is good"; else print  var " is missing"}' xx
foozoo is good
foozoo is missing
```

Now, when I supply a non-existing string the `awk` will return nothing, which make sense as there is no `else` block.

```
awk -v RS='' -v var=THIS_DOES_NOT_EXIST '{$1=$1}; {if(match($0,var)) if(match($0,var ".*good")) print var " is good"; else print  var " is missing"}' xx
```

When I put else block and search for an existing, string in the input. I get this, I do not want this. I only want the `foozoo is good` and `foozoo is bad` lines.

```
awk -v RS='' -v var=foozoo '{$1=$1}; {if(match($0,var)) {if(match($0,var ".*good")) print var " is good"; else print  var " is missing"} else {print "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED"}}' xx
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
foozoo is good
foozoo is missing
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
```

Similarly, when I run for non-existing data, I get the line `NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED` for each, record, **how to print just one line saying data does not exist.**

```
awk -v RS='' -v var=monkistrying '{$1=$1}; {if(match($0,var)) {if(match($0,var ".*good")) print var " is good"; else print  var " is missing"} else {print "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED"}}' xx
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
```

---

Here's that last script above formatted legibly by `gawk -o-`:

```
{
        $1 = $1
}

{
        if (match($0, var)) {
                if (match($0, var ".*good")) {
                        print var " is good"
                } else {
                        print var " is missing"
                }
        } else {
                print "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED"
        }
}
```

Comment: You (and we) will find your code easier to understand and debug if you don't cram it all onto 1 line. Format it sensibly with line breaks, indenting, etc., especially for posting on a forum to ask for help with it. Run `gawk -o-` on it if you're not sure how to format it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me that you only want to print `NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED` *if* no matches (`foozoo` and `good`) are found *and* then only print one occurrence of `NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED`; if this is correct, one idea would be to keep track of the number of matches and in an `END{...}` block if that count is zero then print the single occurrence of `NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED` ...

Found a match:

```
awk -v RS='' -v var=foozoo '
    { $1=$1 }
    { if(match($0,var)) {
        # found++                              # uncomment if both "is good" AND "is missing" should be considered as "found"
        if(match($0,var ".*good"))
          { print var " is good"; found++ }    # remove "found++" if the previous line is uncommented
        else 
          { print var " is missing"       }
      }
    }
END { if (!found) print "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED" }
' xx

foozoo is good
foozoo is missing
```

Found no matches:

```
awk -v RS='' -v var=monkistrying  '
    { $1=$1 }
    { if(match($0,var)) {
        # found++
        if(match($0,var ".*good")) 
          { print var " is good"; found++ }
        else
          { print var " is missing"       }
      }
    }
END { if (!found) print "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED" }
' xx

NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to compress your records onto individual lines, that's just wasting time and potentially making the comparisons harder, and by using `match()` you're treating `var` as a regexp and doing a partial record comparison when it looks like you just want a string full-field comparison. Try `match($0,var)` when the input contains `badfoozoohere` and `foozoo` given `-v var=foozoo` to see one way in which the way you're using `match()` will fail (there are several others). Also since you aren't using RSTART or RLENGTH, using `match($0,var)` instead of `$0 ~ var` was inefficient anyway.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="" }
$2 == var {
    print var, "is", ( $NF == "good" ? "good" : "missing" )
    found = 1
}
END {
    if ( !found ) {
        print "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v var='foozoo' -f tst.awk file
foozoo is good
foozoo is missing
```

```
$ awk -v var='monkistrying' -f tst.awk file
NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED
```

Answer (score 0):

single-pass `awk` based solution w/o needing to transform the data:

- bytes `xC0 \300`, `xC1 \301`, and `xF9 \371` aren't `UTF-8` valid,

  so chances of them appearing in input data are absolutely minuscule

**INPUT**

```
name: foobar
data: 123 bad

name: foozoo
data: 123 good

name: foozoo
data: 123 bad

name: zoobar
data: 123 good

name: barzpp
data: 123 bad
```

**CODE** (`gawk`, `mawk 1/2`, or `LC_ALL=C nawk`)

```
{m,n~,g}awk '
 BEGIN {
     ______ = "NON-EXISTING_DATA_REQUESTED\n"
         FS = "((data|name): ([0-9]+ )?|\n)+"
         RS = "^$" (ORS = _)
        ___ = "\300"
       ____ =  "\371"
      _____ =(_="\301")(__="foozoo")(\
        OFS = _)
 } ! (  NF *= /name: foozoo[ \n]/) ? $NF = ______\
    : gsub(_____  "bad"_, (_)(___)_) +            \
      gsub(_____ "good"_,(_)(____)_) + gsub("[\1-~]+","")+\
      gsub( ___, __ " is missing\n") +                     \
      gsub(____, __ " is " "good\n") + gsub((___)"|"(_)("|")____,"")'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
foozoo is good
foozoo is missing
```