# awk regex escape coming as variable

Tags: awk

How to regex on the dynamic input which may have `brackets` in it.  Here, I am supplying input via the bash command line. This input is coming from some other program that sometimes contains brackets in it and then my simple good old  `$0 ~ var` construct is failing.

Here is my input data:

```
hello there
this is monk
and this is a random data
piano (sense) is cool
which makes no (sense) to anyone
```

Command-1: worked, without brackets around the var. Eg: sense

```
awk -v var='sense' '$0 ~ var {print "worked"}' input
worked
```

Command-2: worked, when I used `.` (dot) in place of brackets `(` and `)`.

```
awk -v var='no .sense.' '$0 ~ var{print "worked"}' input
worked
```

**Command-3:** Here I need to supply input with brackets `(` and `)`. Things go crazy and I get no results. `awk` silently failed by giving a false negative.

```
awk -v var='no (sense)' '$0 ~ var {print "worked"}' input
```

I have already tried `$0 ~ var` and `match($0, var)` they both exhibits the same behavior. I have also tried, the following but it failed miserably. Although the input var is dynamic I cannot do manual escaping as it is coming from some other program.

```
awk -v var='no \(sense\)' 'match($0,var){print "worked"}' input
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'
```

**Question is,** How to supply an input variable that may contain brackets to awk and awk should be able to do sane regex operation on it.  Is it just impossible to do?

**TLDR:**

when working with the above sample input data, when  `var` is `no (sense)`, it should **ONLY** return `which makes no (sense) to anyone`

Comment: I warned you about that in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721923/1745001) and told you that's why I was doing full string instead of partial regexp matching, as you should be doing.

Comment: Please add `piano (sense) is cool` to your sample input and update the expected output accordingly.

Comment: @EdMorton, I got your point now, after updating I am getting two `worked`

Comment: You should ask a new question as you're still accepting regexp answers and so there are more surprises waiting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to ditch regex and use plain string search using `index` function:

```bash
awk -v var='no (sense)' 'index($0, var) {print "worked"; exit}' file

worked
```

btw if you want to escape then use `\\` to escape special characters like this:

```bash
awk -v var='(^|[[:blank:]])no \\(sense\\)([[:blank:]]|$)' '
$0 ~ var {print "worked"; exit}' file
```

However if you must use regex and you cannot pre-escape content of `var` then you can escape all special characters in the `BEGIN` block like this:

```bash
awk -v var='no (sense)' '
BEGIN {
   gsub(/[^_[:alnum:] ]/, "\\\\&", var)
   var = "(^|[[:blank:]])" var "([[:blank:]]|$)"
}
$0 ~ var {print "worked"; exit}
' file

worked
```

Comment: The solution with `BEGIN{}` is clever, however, if the regex is mixed literal '(' and grouping '(' , it may have a problem distinguishing them

Comment: Yes assumption is that we are getting a string content in `var` not the pre-built regular expression

Comment: yes, of course, the developer must tell, which `(` is the literal one and which he wants to have the special meaning. same for other chars, e.g., `|,[,/ ....`  No matter if it's a pre-built regex or a regex-string, the gsub replacement could be a bit too coarst.

Comment: Hello Anubhav, Thanks for your response. Your answer worked really well for me. However,  the answer is ignoring the word boundaries. It was my mistake of not to mention that specifically about it. Is there any fix to make it ignore `piano (sense)` ?

Comment: @monk: I have modified my answer to handle these cases. Please check.

Comment: the 3rd command in the answer is working fine for my edge cases as well. Thanks!

Comment: @monk you probably have more edge cases coming you just haven't come up with test cases for yet. Again - ask a new question.

Comment: @anubhava : not sure if u realize this, but your escaping code leads to this : `\ⲣ\Ⲥ\ⲥ\Ⲧ\ⲧ\Ⲩ\㋮\㋯\㋰\㋱\㋲\搯\搰\搱\⛰\⛱\⛲\⛳ … ` etc etc

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: I don't really see any requirement of handling unicode characters in question. We cannot create imaginary requirements and start solving that.

Comment: @anubhava : i'm just saying that `regex` may have unintended effects if used more generally. besides, even if we stay within `ASCII`, it would escape every control byte, including tabs `\t \v`, form feed `\f`, `SUBSEP` itself, and the null byte.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to escape those characters having special meanings in ERE, you can consider using character class:

```
$ awk -v var='no [(]sense[)]' '$0 ~ var {print "worked"}' file
worked
```

IMO, `[]` could be easier to read than escapes in some cases.

Comment: As the input data comes from a different tool, I cannot do any manipulation like `[(]` or `\(`. manipulation has to be done inside `awk` realm

Answer (score 0):

**INPUT**

```
hello there
this is monk
and this is a random data
which makes no (sense) to anyone
```

**CODE**

```
 {m,n,g}awk -v __='no (sense)' '
 BEGIN {
    gsub("[[-\140!-/\\]{-~:-@]",
                   "[&]",    __)
    gsub(/[\\^]/, "\\\\&",__)
     OFS = "worked"
     FS  = "^.*[^[:alpha:]]?"(__)".*$" } NF*=!_<NF'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
worked
```

To give a sense what those 2 `gsub()` does to `ASCII` :

```
 anything from "!" to "~" that isn't alphanumeric gets 
 safely "caged" in square brackets, 

 regardless of whether it's considered metacharacter or not, 
 which differs among awk flavors.
```

=

```
 [!]  ["]  [#]  [$]   [%]  [&]   [']  [(]
 [)]  [*]  [+]  [,]   [-]  [.]   [/]  0
 1    2    3    4     5    6     7    8
 9    [:]  [;]  [<]   [=]  [>]   [?]  [@]

 A    B    C    D     E    F     G    H
 I    J    K    L     M    N     O    P
 Q    R    S    T     U    V     W    X
 Y    Z    [[]  [\\]  []]  [\^]  [_]  [`]

 a    b    c    d     e    f     g    h
 i    j    k    l     m    n     o    p
 q    r    s    t     u    v     w    x
 y    z    [{]  [|]   [}]  [~]
```